# Using different Variable in an equation base of gender

Tags: javascript, var

I'm trying to calculate the Wilks Score of a lifter and the formula i'm using calls for different variable used in the equations between male and female lifters. How come it keeps returning the male formula instead of the female version.

```
<div id="wilks">
        <select id="gender">
            <option value="male">Male</option>
            <option value="female">Female</option>

        </select>
        <br>
        <input id="big3Total" type="text" placeholder="Big 3 Total">
        <input id="bodyWeight" type="text" name="" placeholder="Bodyweight in Lbs">
        <button onclick="wilks()">Calculate</button>
        <p id="wilksScore"></p>

</div>

<script>  
function wilks() {
 var gender = document.getElementById("gender");
            if ( gender == 'male') {
                a = -216.0475144;
                b = 16.2606339;
                c = -0.002388645;
                d = -0.00113732;
                e = 7.01863E-06;
                f = -1.291E-08;
            } else {
                a = 594.31747775582;
                b = -27.23842536447;
                c = 0.82112226871;
                d = -0.00930733913;
                e = 4.731582E-05;
                f = -9.054E-08;
            }

            var big3Total = document.getElementById('big3Total').value * 0.453592;
            var bodyWeight = document.getElementById('bodyWeight').value * 0.453592;
            var wilks = big3Total * (500 / (a + (b * bodyWeight) + (c * Math.pow(bodyWeight, 2)) + (d * Math.pow(bodyWeight, 3)) + (e * Math.pow(bodyWeight, 4)) + (f * Math.pow(bodyWeight, 5))));
            document.getElementById('wilksScore').innerHTML = "Your Wilks score is: " + wilks.toFixed(2);

        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing this line:

```
var gender = document.getElementById("gender");
```

With the following:

```
var gender = document.getElementById("gender").value;
```

Comment: You can directly read `genderSelectObject.value`. Or just `document.getElementById("gender").value`.

Answer (score 0):

whenever you use a dom api to request for any dom element, what you get is a html node. `document.getElementById` returned the select node.

```
var gender = document.getElementById("gender");
console.log(gender) // outputs the node of type HTMLSelectElement

console.log(HTMLSelectElement[Symbol.hasInstance](gender)); // true

gender.value; // gives you the value of the current selected option
```

what you were actually doing is comparing the `select` node to `"male"`, which will always evaluate to false

your test should be

```
if ( gender.value === ... ) {
   // do something
}
```